# modificar apariencia de jslider modificando el look and feel en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, netbeans-11.2, look-and-feel

estoy montando un reproductor en netbeans y quisiera modificar jslider, por que el proyecto lleva un diseño "minimalista",por lo que entiendo se modifica con archivos xml,lo otro es que yo no quiero hacerlo desde cero, solo quiero modificar algunos parametro:

[image: lo que quiero vs lo q tengo]
.
.

por ahora uso el predefinido pero la idea es lograr que se vea como el primero

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta, **específicamente**?. Qué has logrado? Qué código has utilizado? Qué te ha funcionado? Qué **no** te ha funcionado? En qué te podemos ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour]  del sitio, saludos.

Comment: entonces deveria explicar con edits lo q avanzo con el problema??